# Не запускаются примеры с cocos2d-x.org

Tags: c++, cocos2d

В данный момент я читаю гайд для программистов по cocos2d-x. Почти каждая глава сопровождается примером кода, который предлагается взять на github. Я создаю новый проект, копирую туда весь код с github. Копирую куда надо картинки. Но когда я запускаю проект, у меня появляется окно с первоначальной картинкой кокоса вместо игры. Что мне сделать, чтобы все-таки запустились примеры?